# Intergrate proguard with android in mac os x

Tags: android, proguard

I'm struggeling intergrated proguard with android in my mac os computer.
My proguard android sdk is located at :

```
 /Users/thanhnguyen/Documents/mr thao's music/android-sdk-macosx/tools/proguard
```

Proguard.sh file at follow :

```
 PROGUARD_HOME=`dirname "$0"`/..

  java -jar $PROGUARD_HOME/lib/proguard.jar "$@"
```

My project.properties as follow:

```
 proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

When i try to run proguard, this errors occured :

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Proguard Error 1 
Output: 
Error: /Users/thanhnguyen/Documents/mr thao (No such file or directory)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.runProguard(BuildHelper.java:623)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:259)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.doExport(ExportWizard.java:313)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.access$0(ExportWizard.java:238)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$1.run(ExportWizard.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks a alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have an apostrophe in your folder name ("mr thao's music").

When Proguard reads in this file name, it hits the the apostrophe and thinks that it has reached the end of the file name, thus why the error shows that it is looking for a directory called `/Users/thanhnguyen/Documents/mr thao`.

I would either rename the directory or move your Proguard home elsewhere. In general, special characters in file or path names is not a good idea, as it will occasionally cause issues like this.

Alternatively, you could manually pass the directory in the `java -jar command` in progaurd.sh and escape the single quote/apostrophe with a backslash like so:

```
java -jar "/Users/thanhnguyen/Documents/mr thao\'s music/android-sdk-macosx/tools/proguard/lib/proguard.jar" "$@"
```

Keep in mind that this method will cause issues if this project is shared with other people, as the directory will be wrong for them.

Comment: Where/which files should I change the path to /Users/thanhnguyen/Documents/mr thao\'s music/android-sdk-macosx/tools/proguard?

Comment: Ah, my bad, I thought you had defined that in your config files. I updated my answer.

Comment: It seem that i aslo have problem with spaces in in path name as this errors occured                                                   :Caused by: Proguard Error 1 
Output: 
Unable to access jarfile /Users/thanhnguyen/Documents/mr

Comment: Try escaping those with a backslash as well.